# How to revoke OAuth access tokens in ADFS 3.0?

Tags: oauth, adfs

We are currently looking at rolling out ADFS 3.0 (Server 2012 R2). I've searched high and low, but it doesn't seem possible to revoke access and/or refresh tokens that have been issued by ADFS 3.0. Has any one accomplished this?

I'm also inclined to place an API in front of ADFS to handle revocation and audit/logging, but it seems this may be a 'hacked' solution.

Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general OAuth2 tokens cannot be revoked (ie there is no signout). The applicable mechanism just disables a refresh.... This is radically different from WS-Fed passive and SAML2 browser SSO.